# WooCommerce Local Pickup Plus makes the shipping address empty in profile

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am working on local pickup plus. There was one issue that needed discussion. When I chose the local pick plus location in checkout and make an order it deleted the shipping address fields from the account page.

The local pickup plus address

```
<input type="text" id="_address_1" name="_address_1" class="address_1" value="Storgatan 24" spellcheck="false" data-ms-editor="true">
```

and the shipping address input

```
<input type="text" class=" input-text    " name="shipping_address_1" id="shipping_address_1" placeholder="Gatunamn och nummer" address-line1="" value="Aqil kor" data-placeholder="Gatunamn och nummer">
```

As you can see the ID for WooCom address one is shipping_address_1 and in local pickup plus is _address_1 which is totally different.

Then why does it affects the profile address?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid user registration data to be updated each time an order is placed use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_customer_data', '__return_false' );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.